# Storing present firefox/chrome URL in file

Tags: linux, bash, url, firefox, google-chrome

I want to store the present firefox/chrome URL into a temporary file. Is there any way to accomplish this using bash console or the C programming language ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current Firefox session is stored in `sessionstore.js`, it can be found in the Firefox profile folder.